# Set a field value in a base class that can be overridden in child classes in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that looks like this:

```
public class Animal
{
  public string _name = "Animal";

  public string GetGreeting()
  {
    if (this._name == "Animal")
    {
      return "Hello friend!";
    }
    else
    {
      return $"Hello, '{this._name}'";
    }
  }
}

public class Tiger : Animal
{
  // How do I set "_name" here?
}
```

I want to hard-code the `_name` value in the `Tiger` class. However, I don't want to force other classes to set the `_name` value. How do I do that in C#?

Comment: note: public fields are usually a very bad idea - IMO `public string Name {get;set;}` would be a far better idea

Comment: Your hierarchy is pretty strange IMHO. What should `new Animal()` return? I suppose the base-class shouldn't be instantiable. Better make it `abstract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a constructor:

```cs
public Tiger()
{
    _name = "Tony"; // they're great!
}
```